# dumpdecrypted.dylib: missing LC_DYLD_INFO load command

Tags: ios, header-files, jailbreak

when i use dumpdecrypted.dylib to crack app,i got below:
"dyld: could not load inserted library 'dumpdecrypted.dylib' because no suitable image found.  Did find:
dumpdecrypted.dylib: missing LC_DYLD_INFO load command"
Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I used flag for clang, that to set min iOS version for my lib.

```bash
-miphoneos-version-min=12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

dumpdecrypted to compile with the same SDK version as the iOS version, works fine. Open "Terminal (Terminal)", type xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path. My output is
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk

If the device and xcode's sdk are not the same version, you need to modify the makefile

My system version is iOS8.3,
so the modification is as follows
SDK=`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`
for
SDK=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk

(This iPhoneOS8.X.sdk needs to go to the Internet to download the old version of xcode, and then extract the old version of the sdk, see the description below for the extraction method, and then put it in the same directory as the new version of the sdk, above SDK=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/ Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.X.sdk)

8.3 sdk is backward compatible, that is, 8.3 is compatible with 8.0 8.1 ....
The path is the path of the downloaded sdk)